# why http request with nodejs gives no response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm creating a simple MERN stack project - the user makes notes with a note model that includes an ObjectId user ref while testing an endpoint it gives me a request sending with no response I need to know why.
here is my code below.

```
//Note model
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);

//create employee schema

    const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: 'User',
        },
        title: {
          type: String,
          required: [true, 'title note is required!'],
        },
        text: {
          type: String,
          required: [true, 'note description is required!'],
        },
        completed: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
      },
      {
        timestamps: true,
      }
    );
    
    noteSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {
      inc_field: 'ticket',
      id: 'ticketNums',
      start_seq: 500,
    });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema);
```

createNote controller code:

please note that req.id was taken from jwt access token.

```
const createNote = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { title, text } = req.body;
  if (!title || !text)
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: 'title and text are required for creating a new note.!',
    });

  const note = await Note.create({
    user: req.id,
    title,
    text,
  });
  return res.status(201);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of you still didn't found the issue, just at the end of your controller add the data you want to return. For example, instead of this

```
return res.status(201);
```

write this:

```
return res.status(201).json({
    message: 'Note created successfully!',
    note,
});
```

everything else seems ok..